# pattern.Invoke() exception: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I'm new to c#.
I'm looking for solution to this (app to check can be downloaded from http://download.eset.com/special/ESETLogCollector.exe

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Automation;


namespace LogCollector
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
            proc.UseShellExecute = true;
            proc.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            proc.FileName = "C:\\robot\\ESETLogCollector.exe";
            proc.Verb = "runas";
            Process.Start(proc);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Ahoj");
            AutomationElement desktop = AutomationElement.RootElement;
            Condition cond = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "ESET Log Collector");
            AutomationElement elc = desktop.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, cond);
            Console.WriteLine(elc.Current.Name);
            String save_path = "";
            Condition cond1 = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "1005");
            try
            {
                AutomationElement save_as = elc.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, cond1);
                Console.WriteLine(save_as.Current.AutomationId);
                save_path = save_as.Current.Name;
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EX: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(save_path))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(save_path);
                Console.WriteLine(save_path);
            }

            Condition cond2 = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "1002");
            AutomationElement collect = elc.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, cond2);
            Console.WriteLine(collect.Current.Name);
            try
            {
                Object outObject;
                collect.TryGetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern, out outObject);
                InvokePattern pattern = outObject as InvokePattern;
                pattern.Invoke();
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EX: {0}", e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

All I still got IF I Want to invoke buttonclick is:
Operation is not valid due to the current stat of the object

I really don't know what is happening here. Can anybody help me with this?

Ty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operation is probably failing because you are not running your automation application as administrator while the ESET Log Collector has been run with elevated permissions.

The [UI Automation Security Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742884.aspx) describes the security model and how to communicate with processes that are running at a higher privilege level (i.e. you need a signed application with a manifest file that includes a special attribute).

Comment: I tried to run Visual Studio as administrator and this makes the 'magic'. Thank you